# Edit virtual host file using php

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

I have a php application and somethings related to the application need changes to vhost.conf file.

Presently i'm making the changes manually. But i would like to automate it using a php script.

Is this advisable? I want to know the security complications involved.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible, or advisable? The latter will be somewhat subjective and thus not a great question for SO.

Comment: It's certainly possible. But advisable, nope.

Comment: @BenM I believe it's possible since vhost is just a file. I would like to know the security complications involved and how i can takle them. Thanks

Comment: Then you should probably ask this question on SuperUser, rather than SO since you already know how to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible. As long as PHP (probably running under Apache) has access to the virtual hosts config file it's as simple as appending data to the file and calling `exec('sudo apache2 restart');`.

Is it advisable? **No.** If you're accepting any type of user input you're opening yourself up to a security vulnerability if you miss even one piece of input sanitation. Even if you lock down the page to require authentication there could be something you missed.

If you want to make it easier to manage the virtual hosts use some sort of administration software.

What purpose would you need to automatically make vhosts, anyway?